# How to rewrite this LINQ using join with lambda expressions?

Tags: linq, join, lambda

It seems like most LINQ is written with lambda expressions. How do I go about rewriting this linq using lambda, kinda confusion with the style (especially with joins)?

```
var responses =
            from c in questionRepository.GetReponses()
            join o in questionRepository.GetQuestions() on
            c.QuestionID equals o.QuestionID
            where c.UserID == 9999
            orderby o.DisplayOrder
       select new { o.QuestionText, c.AnswerValue };
```

Comment: You don't really need to rewrite it. It's fine as it is, to be honest. Sometimes I use one style and sometimes the other, and this is a case where I'd probably go for the query syntax. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx): `As a rule when you write LINQ queries, we recommend that you use query syntax whenever possible and method syntax whenever necessary.`

Comment: I like this form for JOIN's. With "Lambda Expressions" it requires specifying 4 arguments (plus the receiver) which, while the same as the above, seems more cluttered.

Comment: Though query syntax is easier for joins, lambda syntax is easier to debug.  For details see https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/linq-secrets-revealed-chaining-and-debugging/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I prefer the "LINQ syntax" for Joins as I think it looks cleaner.

In any case, here is how to translate the LINQ-join to the "Lambda Expression"-join.

The translation for:

```
from a in AA
join b in BB on
a.Y equals b.Y
select new {a, b}
```

Is:

```
AA.Join(                 // L
  BB,                    // R
  a => a.Y, b => b.Y,    // L -> join value, R -> join value
  (a, b) => new {a, b})  // L+R result
```

The other LINQ keywords are much simpler to convert (e.g. `OrderBy(u => u.DisplayOrder)` and are just "chained together" with `.`. - give it a go!

Comment: I think you are missing a comma between b => b.Y  and (a, b) => new {a, b}

I new at this I could be wrong.

Answer (score 9):

```
var responses = questionRepository.GetReponses()
                   .Join(questionRepository.GetQuestions(), 
                         c => c.QuestionID,
                         o => o.QuestionID,
                         (c, o) => new {c, o})
                   .Where(x => x.c.UserID == 99999)
                   .OrderBy(x => x.o.DisplayOrder)
                   .Select(x => new {x.o.QuestionText, x.c.AnswerValue});
```