# How to convert a multiple conditions like this to lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I'm aiming to do a lamba expression with this query, and I'm stuck. I had to do some easy lambdas before and now I need to do a multiple condition mixing or and ands in this one and I'm new with this.

So let me explain a bit of a this structure and you will see why is tricky (at least for a newbie at lambda). I have Requests, where request have many attributes, attributes have name and value, because according to request State they have different attributes in this case `RequestState.APPROVAL_PENDING` is a constant that will bring the right state and attribute name have being also compared with constants with the attribute names I need and the value need find is wwid in the attribute value.

Then I will make a query.tolist(); and get all the requests, but I need to find out how to lambda this.

```
var query = from request in DBContext.REQUESTs
                        join attr in DBContext.REQUEST_ATTRIBUTES on request.REQUEST_ID equals attr.REQUEST_ID
                        where (attr.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE == wwid && 
                        (attr.ATTRIBUTE_NAME == RequestAttributes.APPROVER_2_WWID || attr.ATTRIBUTE_NAME == RequestAttributes.APPROVER_WWID))
                        && request.STATE_ID == RequestState.APPROVAL_PENDING
                        select request;
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692015/how-to-rewrite-this-linq-using-join-with-lambda-expressions)? What you have is more readable.

Comment: @daniel-vega. Did my answer work for you ?

Comment: @Boney, not really i changed my approach on that time

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = DBContext.REQUESTs.Where(request => request.STATE_ID == RequestState.APPROVAL_PENDING)
                        .Join(DBContext.REQUEST_ATTRIBUTES.Where(attr => attr.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE == wwid &&
                                (attr.ATTRIBUTE_NAME == RequestAttributes.APPROVER_2_WWID || attr.ATTRIBUTE_NAME == RequestAttributes.APPROVER_WWID)),
                            request => request.REQUEST_ID,
                            attr => attr.REQUEST_ID,
                            (request, attr) => request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing this.

Create a navigation property from Request to RequestAttributes:

```
 public class Request
{
    .... Properties...
    public virtual ICollection<RequestAttribute> RequestAttributes { get; set; }
}
public class RequestAttribute
{
    .... Properties...
    public virtual Request> Request { get; set; }
}
```

This creates a one to many relationship from Request to RequestAttributes. And your query becomes:

```
var query = DBContext.REQUESTs.Where(r=> r.REQUEST_ATTRIBUTES.Any(attr=>attr.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE == wwid && 
                    (attr.ATTRIBUTE_NAME == RequestAttributes.APPROVER_2_WWID || attr.ATTRIBUTE_NAME == RequestAttributes.APPROVER_WWID))
                    && r.STATE_ID == RequestState.APPROVAL_PENDING)
                    .Select(r=> r);
```